# Auto Save a CSV File to pre-defined location with pre-defined file name

Tags: php, file, csv, directory, autosave

Suppose i have a web page from where i download a csv file. A dialog box then appears which has the options 'Open'or 'Save' file. Now, what i want is that as soon as the user clicks on the download button, the csv file automatically gets saved to a pre defined location, without any dialog box appearing on screen. Also, i want the file to be saved with a pre-defined file name in that location, and over write any existing files of same type if already present there. Is it possible? (am using firefox as browser). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your trying to modify client browser settings... Well try

Comment: No, this is absolutely not possible with PHP.